# Change navbar background from transparent to black

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My webpages use navbar navigation. The website was built from a bootstrap template. The navbar is a sticky and appears to transition from transparent background to a black background on scroll down. I want to have the black background present at all times for the navbar. Is this controlled in bootstrap.min.js or bootstrap.min.css and what should I search for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add this in your nav class <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">

Comment: set a breaking point for event listeners listening for mouse wheel using the inspector or DevTools. And check the source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `navbar-dark bg-dark` on the navbar classes

Answer (score 0):

You should add 'bg-dark' to your class

plus you can view this page to learn more about boostrap classes and colors:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/

Answer (score 0):

Give a class name to the div in which your navbar is wrapped and in CSS change the background colour to black
OR

```html
<div style="background-color: black"> 
    <!-- NAVBAR -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the jquery file from the template that has navbar scroll property 
and then give color to the navbar background in the css.
Hope it works! Try starting code for more help!!!